# What's the intuitive, geometric meaning of torsion in homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, intuition

If we consider the homology groups $H_n(X)$ of a topological space $X$—say a CW complex for example—one can interpret every free summand of $H_n(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} ^k \oplus T$ as an $n$-dimensional "hole". Compare with [this collecition of informal examples on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(mathematics)#Informal_examples).

If we consider the torsion summand $T$ though, what geometrical/intuitive meaning does this torsion with respect to $X$? For example, what does it mean about $X$ if $T = \mathbb{Z}/(a)$ for $a \neq 1, 0$?

Comment: The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170056/intuition-of-non-free-homology-groups?rq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40149/intuition-of-the-meaning-of-homology-groups?noredirect=1&lq=1) might be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition of non-free homology groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170056/intuition-of-non-free-homology-groups)