# intution behind homology

Tags: algebraic-topology

i am currently studying a course in homology theory and have done a basic introductory course in algebraic topology which deals with the idea of the fundamental groups and their topological invariance.I am really stuck in getting through the basic idea of homology ,espacially , what properties of the space does it reveals which cannot be answered by considering the fundamental group of the spaces or any other properties which reflects its importance over the study of fundamental groups?

if possible, give a detailed explanation...

also,suggest some reference texts

thanks a lot.....

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40149/intuition-of-the-meaning-of-homology-groups